# How to access files deployed in aws elasticbeanstalk

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have deployed node.js code on aws elasticbeanstalk creating a new environment. The app is successfully deployed. I want to access the files. I used ssh to the remote machine but the I can't find the code

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Elastic Beanstalk places the deployed code in `/var/app/current`

Note that you shouldn't be making changes on the Elastic Beanstalk server directly.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to the last answer, remember that you need to select enable SSH to your instances when launching application. Else, you won't be able to SSH into any AWS Elastic Beanstalk instance.

Answer (score 0):

If you found this question but you're not using ssh, you could download the zip after clicking on a version in the console.